# Displaying two labels for one second through a timer

Tags: c#, timer, label, visible

I'm making a little game in C#
When the score is 100, I want two labels to display for one second, then they need to be invisible again.

At the moment I have in Form1:

```
void startTimer(){
 if (snakeScoreLabel.Text == "100"){
  timerWIN.Start();
 }
}

private void timerWIN_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int timerTick = 1;
  if (timerTick == 1)
  {
    lblWin1.Visible=true;
    lblWin2.Visible=true;
  }
  else if (timerTick == 10)
  {
    lblWin1.Visible = false;
    lblWin2.Visible = false;
    timerWIN.Stop();
  }

  timerTick++;

}
```

The timer's interval is 1000ms.

Problem = labels aren't showing at all

Timers are pretty new to me, so I'm stuck here :/

Comment: Have you verified that the code to make the labels visible actually executes? That is, are you sure that the `timerWIN_tick` method is executed? And what sets the `timerTick` variable?

Comment: It doesn't execute at the moment

Comment: Which is actually part of my problem :/

Comment: snakeScoreLabel.Text != "100" or startTimer() never ran. otherwise, the label should always be shown since if (timerTick == 1) is always true.

Comment: I would turn the labels on, then start the timer, then in the tick event handler I would turn the labels off and stop the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
void startTimer()
{ 
     if (snakeScoreLabel.Text == "100")
     {
      System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000) { Enabled = true }; 
      timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => 
        { 
           lblWin1.Visible=true;
           timer.Dispose(); 
        }; 
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try multithreaded System.Threading.Timer :

```
public int TimerTick = 0;
        private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
        public void StartTimer()
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
                                                    {
                                                        if (TimerTick == 10)
                                                        {
                                                            Invoke((Action) (() =>
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     label1.Visible = false;
                                                                                     label2.Visible = false;
                                                                                 }));
                                                            _timer.Dispose();
                                                            TimerTick = 0;
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            TimerTick++;
                                                        }

                                                    }, null, 0, 1000);

        }
```